# PyQt reading text from a QTextEdit widget

Tags: python, pyqt, qtextedit

I am trying to write a program which reads data in from a file into a QTextEdit box and also a QTable widget. You should be able to edit the data in the textedit and the changes should appear in the table and viceversa.

My problem is that when I read data back out of the textedit box into a file or variable, it gets rid of the newline character so when I try to use a `for line in text` statement, the result gives me single characters instead of lines. However, when I print the variable text to the screen, however, it appears correctly with newlines in the right places.

Here is some sample code:

```
for line in self.entries[FileDisplay].toPlainText():            
    print line
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is very litte code to go on here, however I think this is what is happening.

It seems like you are iterating over the returned string from the QTextBox, when you call `for line in text` it is iterating over the characters, as strings don't usually iterate over newlines. When you are printing it out, it is printing all characters, *including the newlines*, so it appears that ever thing is working properly

Try this instead:

```
for line in text.split('\n')
```